# What does JSLint's "Bad Escapement" mean in this case?

Tags: javascript, jslint

I thougth "bad escapement" stands for wrong use escaping with slash.

Why does JSLint bring up the message in this function on the 3d line (for...)?

```
  function splitTags(commaSeparated) {
    var tagArray = commaSeparated.split(','); 
    for (var i=(tagArray.length) - 1; i>=0; i = i - 1 ){
      tagArray[i] = f.trim(tagArray[i]);
    }    
    return tagArray;
  }
  f.splitTags=splitTags;
```

*Edit:* I changed the "i--" to "i=i-1"  and posted the changed version above.

Lint complains at character 30, which is the first minus sign.

*Edit2:* After this change it does not complain anymore. New version that works:

```
  function splitTags(commaSeparated) {
    var tagArray = commaSeparated.split(',');
    var startWith = tagArray.length - 1; 
    for (var i=startWith; i>=0; i = i - 1 ){
      tagArray[i] = f.trim(tagArray[i]);
    }    
    return tagArray;
  }
  f.splitTags=splitTags;
```

Strange. I am actually using JSLint multi: http://ajaxian.com/archives/jslint-multi

So this is not solved but I have a workaround. But would be nice to get the real answer, I still have many of such code parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess from the workaround that I posted in the Edit of the question that JSLint multi does not like the `length` keyword in the *for* line at all.

Do not use *length* there but calculate it in the line before and use a variable.

A rule to make JSLint multi not complain.

Answer (score 0):

From the [JSLint page](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html):

JSLint expects that + will not be followed by + or ++, and that - will not be followed by - or --. A misplaced space can turn + + into ++, an error that is difficult to see. Use parens to avoid confusion..

Comment: This is something differnt. I turned off ++/-- checking. But I will fix and repeat linting...

Comment: I changed it and updated the question. Thank you but this was not the solution. Still unsolved.